# validating user's input in wizard control

Tags: asp.net, wizard

i am using a wizard control with few textboxes in it and i want to validate them how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use validation summary along with requiredfield validator. Custom validator or regular expression validator. Many examples of how to do this on the web. Cheere